# How to access current row data in datasource from ITemplate.InstantiateIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page that includes a gridview I have AutoGenerateColumns="False" and inside the gridview I have
a number of asp:BoundFields and a asp:TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/BaseAndRepeats.aspx?id=" + Eval("ID") %>' Text="Test1"></asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/BaseAndRepeats.aspx?id=" + Eval("description") %>' Text="Test2"></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

ID & description retrieve attributes from the current item (current row) in the actual datasource.

I really want to do something like this (i.e. multiple controls on same row whose appearance
depends on data for that row and also related data) programatically

So I do something like this in my page load (snippet)

```
ROTAEntities1 RE = new ROTAEntities1();
List<Value_Result> _list = RE.myproc(myparam).ToList();
TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
tf.ItemTemplate = new OwnedEventsPage.MyTemplate(RE, _list);
GridView1.Columns.Add(tf);
this.GridView1.DataSource = _list;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

However in InstantiateIn I cannot seem to find a way to access through the container the current row data either 
in the grid or in the datasource.  So I am passing the datasource and anything else I may need to the template on construction and
using a member int to keep track of the row.

However this means the template and InstantiateIn do not stand 
stable on their own but are dependant on a number of assumptions

- the template is newly constructed and added before the bind
- the bind    occurrs straight after  this
- InstantiateIn is always called in       datasource row order

see snippet below:

```
private class MyTemplate : ITemplate
{
    ROTAEntities1 RE;
    int rowCount = 0;
    List<ListOwnedBaseEvents_Result> mylist;

    public MyTemplate(ROTAEntities1 _re, List<Value_Result> _list)
    {
        RE = _re;
        mylist = _list;

    }
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        // can obtain the current DataControlFieldCell but cannot seem to access the
        // current grid or datasource row
        DataControlFieldCell dcfc = (DataControlFieldCell)container;

        int id = mylist[rowCount].ID;
        rowCount++;

        // then I go on to create controls and add to the container
        // making use of id, mylist and other related data entities in RE
        // 
        ...
    }
```

Is there a way that I can get InstantiateIn to know independantly what the current datasource row is 
as it is constructing and adding the controls just like it effectively does if I use the mark up in
the aspx.  I think it would be safer.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find a confirmation for this but I believe the `InstantiateIn` is called before Data Binding, so you have no info about the data at that moment.

What you can do is attach an event handler to the DataBind event of your container and on the handler creates your objects accordingly.

```
public class myTemplate : ITemplate
{

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        container.DataBinding +=container_DataBinding;
    }

    private void container_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get current data item associated with the row where the template is
        var data = DataBinder.GetDataItem(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);

        //I'm supposing I bound an object collection with a property Name, but this is generic like you do with Eval in aspx.
        var fieldValue = DataBinder.Eval(data, "Name");

        //here you can use the field value to add controls to the container, just cast the sender to a Control type
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.  I am guessing I'll need a handler for each control.  unless a way to know which control sender is.  Is NamingContainer the grid cell?  Does DataRowView relate to grid or datasource and is column a member of the template class or just something left out of the snippet. I'll go and look into this myself of course, but if you have any pointers / cautions that would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: In the aspx the hard coded template can access any attributes in the data source even if they are not bound to a field in the grid.

Comment: I changed my answer with a better example

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this out and mark up the post.

Comment: I am working on this and will definitely mark up the post answered.  One thing that's confusing me though.  I read in lots of places that you should only ever ever create dynamic controls in page_init.  Me doing it in InstantiateIn or you in the binding handler goes against this, but seems to work fine.  Is there a risk?  Or is there more to understand about when it has to be done in page_init.  For me it would not be possible, I don't know there which and how many I need, even if I can set other properties later.